# PHP file only capturing certain data from HTML form

Tags: php, html

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I am struggling to get all the information within this form to print properly to email. At present I am receiving data from the 'email', 'checkin' and 'checkout' input fields. However 'name' , 'guests' and 'message' do not appear.

This is the HTML code for the form:

```
    <form class="reservation-vertical clearfix" role="form" method="post" action="php/reservation.php" name="reservationform" id="reservationform">
      <div id="message"></div>
      <!-- Error message display -->
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name"><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Full Name"/>
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your E-mail"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="checkin">Check-in</label>
        <div class="popover-icon" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="Check-in is from 2:00pm"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"> </i> </div>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar infield"></i>
        <input name="checkin" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Check-in"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="checkout">Check-out</label>
        <div class="popover-icon" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="Check-out is by 11:00am"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"> </i> </div>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar infield"></i>
        <input name="checkout" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Check-out"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="guests">Guests</label>
         <i class="fa fa-user infield"></i>
         <input name="guests" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of guests"/>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="extra"> Your message</label>
          <textarea name="extra" rows="9" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enquire Now</button> 
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
    <?php
    if(!$_POST) exit;
    function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

  $name    = $_POST['name'];
  $email    = $_POST['email'];
  $checkin    = $_POST['checkin'];
  $checkout    = $_POST['checkout'];
  $guests    = $_POST['guests'];
  $extra    = $_POST['extra'];


  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $extra = stripslashes($extra);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $guests = stripslashes($guests);
  }


$address = "myemail@gmail.com";
$e_subject = "Hotel booking enquiry submitted by $fullname" . PHP_EOL;
$e_body = "

A hotel booking enquiry has been made by: $name
Their email is: $email
The customer wants to check-in at: $checkin 
and check-out at: $checkout
The customer requested accommodation for: $guests guest(s).
They also included this message: $extra"  . PHP_EOL;

$e_reply = "You can contact the customer via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id=success_page style=text-align:center>";
    echo "<h4>Booking enquiry sent successfully!</h4>";
    echo "<p><br>Thank you, your enquiry has been received. We will contact you shortly to complete your booking.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo "ERROR!";

}
```

Comment: $name    = $_POST['fullname']; - Should that not be $name    = $_POST['name'];

Comment: check print_r($_POST);

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Because `magic_quotes_gpc` has been deprecated in 5.3.x and removed with 5.4 [Warning This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$e_subject = "Hotel booking enquiry submitted by $fullname" . PHP_EOL;
```

Should be

```
$e_subject = "Hotel booking enquiry submitted by $name" . PHP_EOL;
```